# Weisfeiler-Lehman test for hypergraphs

Tags: hypergraph, isomorphism-testing

The Weisfeiler-Lehman test for graph isomorphism is based on iterative graph recoloring and works for almost all graphs, in the probabilistic sense. If we extend the domain to general hypergraphs, does there exist an analogous test for hypergraph isomorphism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can represent a hypergraph by its vertex-edge incidence graph and apply W-L to that.